# Conversion of date 8-DEC-17 to 08/12/2017 is giving 07/12/2017 in python

Tags: python, datetime-format, strftime, mktime

I'm trying to format the datetime in python, and this is what I was trying:

```
import time

datestr = "8-DEC-17"
v=time.strptime(datestr,"%d-%b-%y")
l = time.mktime(v) 
print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y ", time.gmtime(l)))
```

The output of this code is :
**07/12/17** which is not the one I want

I am expecting : **08/12/17**

Comment: I guess because of the timezone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime` which is a bit shorter and gives the result you want:

```
from datetime import datetime 
datetime.strptime(datestr, "%d-%b-%y").strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Comment: Yes it works!!! Thank you so much.Found it difficult to resolve as am new to python..

Comment: @Divya: No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime, `mktime()` is the inverse function of `localtime()`. So, you need to use `localtime()` instead of `gmtime()` to print the result:

```python
print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y ", time.localtime(l)))
```

outputs `08/12/17`

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
datestr = "8-DEC-17"
dt = parse(datestr)
print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

Comment: Welcome @Divya , Happy Coding :) If you like solution you can upvote it Plz.